# Is reporting the test error of the model with the smallest validation error a sound way of doing Early Stopping Regularization?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, regularization, gradient-descent, conv-neural-network

I wanted to use Early Stopping regularization to get the best generalization of my model trained via an iterative algorithm (e.g. some variant of SGD on a NN). I was thinking of implementing this idea as following:

1. Run SGD for N iterations
2. Record train, validation (cv) and test error for each epoch (even possible save the current model each epoch or even just the one with best cv)
3. Then report the test error (and return model) of the epoch with the lowest cross-validation.

Is this a sound way (maybe even shortcut) to implementing Early Stopping Regularization?

I've heard of other methods like track K cross-validation errors, etc but under the condition of sufficient memory space and patience for large N, I thought that maybe this could be a sound method to implement the idea instead.

---

The question is. If I train a NN for 1000 iterations and want to do early stopping. Can I just look at all the validation errors from all steps, note which one is the smallest validation error and then report the models test error relating to that step. Obviously training is only done with the train. The train data is for training, validation for choosing when to early stop and the test for reporting a test error that is not underestimated.

---

I don't understand why the order based on time/iteration even matters honestly, it seem arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

What you call "cross-validation error" should be the "validation error", i.e. the error computed on the validation set, which is a set of labeled samples that appear in neither the training set (otherwise the early stop might not be that early, and you'll overfit) nor the test set (forbidden).

Comment: this seems more of a comment than a question. The question is. If I train a NN for 1000 iterations and want to do early stopping. Can I just look at all the validation errors from all steps, note which one is the smallest validation error and then report the models test error relating to that step. Obviously training is only done with the train. The train data is for training, validation for choosing when to early stop and the test for reporting a test error that is not underestimated.

Comment: @Pinocchio what's the difference with the "traditional" early stopping?

Comment: thats exactly my question :p ! Usually early stopping is described as actually stopping when the validation error starts to increase. This is easy to   do by eye balling it, but in a computer one has to keep track of maybe the last k etc and then stop if it seem sensible. To avoid all that non-sense I was suggesting (in theory), just record *everything* during training and return the model and test error that resulted in the lowest validation error.

Comment: @Pinocchio what's your early stopping criterion?

Comment: right now there isn't one explicitly. Instead, what I am suggesting is to simulate early stopping by choosing the number iterations sufficient large and then just returning the model with lowest validation error (obviously as I've emphasized one cannot return the validation error as an estimate of the generalization error in this case, so we return the current model's test error).

Comment: @Pinocchio I don't think this would qualify as early stop then.

Comment: why not? I don't see the difference? I don't understand why the order based on time/iteration even matters honestly.

Comment: @Pinocchio if the amount of training epochs is predetermined, there is no early stopping.

Comment: But if it the validation error has a U shape and we pick the model at the bottom of the U, how would you even know the difference that I did the method I suggested vs the real early stopping?

Comment: @Pinocchio The early stop wouldn't wait till the end of the U.

Comment: who cares if it goes to end if we report basically the same model. The difference I see is only in number of iterations ran. Real early stopping is computationally quicker, but doesn't intrinsically have a advantage over the method I described, or at least I can't see it. I might be totally wrong though.

Comment: @Pinocchio The only point of early stop is to reduce the number of iterations ran.

Comment: fine its not early stopping because we don't stop early (its just terminology). However, is it a sound method to report generalization of a model is a more important question I'd argue.

Comment: @Pinocchio Reporting the test error of the model with the smallest validation error is what people typically do.

Comment: even in this context of reporting the model with the smallest validation across iterations during training? For some reason it just feels like cheating. I might be wrong (thanks for your patience and having this dicussion with me)

Comment: @Pinocchio Yes, it is fine. That's the job of the validation set. (It would be cheating if you were reporting the smallest test set error.)

Comment: Why do you write that "The only point of early stop is to reduce the number of iterations ran."?  The main point of early stopping is to avoid overfitting, not to reduce computation time.